# Converting javascript array.map to php array_map

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is a javascript code that consists of hashmap array(keys:value).I created one function using map that returns values of entered keys.

```
var rule = 
{
"c": "d",
"a": "o",
"t": "g",
"h": "a",
"e": "n",
"n": "t"
}
function convert(str) {
return [...str].map(d => rule[d]).join('')
}
console.log(convert("cat"))
//prints dog
```

Now I want to convert above javascript code in php so that i can run it under php server.
I created same array in php as

```
$rule = 
{
"c" => "d",
"a" => "o",
"t" => "g",
"h" => "a",
"e" => "n",
"n" => "t"
}
```

Using array_map,how to convert in php code in same way as done in javascript. Php syntax for array_map is

```
array_map(myfunction,array1,array2...)
```

Comment: _“but I dont get the php syntax for array_map”_ - what exactly don’t you “get” about it? The manual has multiple examples showing how to use this.

Comment: I have used map inside the function in javascript but in php,syntax seems little odd to me.I am new to php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such function exists in php

```
echo strtr('cat', $rule);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47c2cd9d5cb396f68ad22f5babc1e69525e44cc2)

EDIT:

To do with array_map

```
echo join('', array_map(function($x) use($rule) { return $rule[$x]; }, str_split('cat')));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/937ac679491d3c43fd2565706ca96738e8553f2e)

Comment: I want to do in php using array_map in same way as above javascript code.Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Thank you I got the logic behind it.